# Why does my default django admin page look terrible when deployed to heroku?

Tags: django, heroku, admin

I finally deployed my django project to heroku but for some reason the styling of the admin page looks really ugly. I have no idea why that is.

Comment: what does it looklike? is it without style?

Comment: yes it is definitely without style.

Comment: Did you check how to handle staticfiles with heroku ? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets

Comment: I use Django 4.0.1. And i think the one on Heroku is not supported by this version????

Comment: How do i fix all the static file issues in Django 4.0.1. The BASE_DIR variable seems to be different on mine.

Comment: @SudoSu, Heroku uses whatever version of Django you have defined as a dependency.